# How to use the addr2line command in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, valgrind, addr2line

I am trying to use addr2line command in Unix but everytime it is giving the same output as ??:0. I am giving command as `addr2line -e  a.out  0x4005BDC` . I got this address while running this a.out executable with `valgrind` tool to find the memory leakage. I also compiled the source code with `-g` option.

Answer (score 39):

You can also use gdb instead of addr2line to examine memory address. Load executable file in gdb and print the name of a symbol which is stored at the address. [16 Examining the Symbol Table](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html).

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x4005BDC
```

Comment: Good idea. Also running the program in gdb with a breakpoint at that address and getting the backtrace could give good information about what exactly is happening there.

Comment: See also (gdb) info line * 0x4005BDC

Comment: The (library) code address would be the same or different, between compiling with "-g" flag and without the flag ?

Answer (score 31):

You need to specify an *offset* to addr2line, not a virtual address (VA).  Presumably if you had address space randomization turned off, you could use a full VA, but in most modern OSes, address spaces are randomized for a new process.

Given the VA `0x4005BDC` by valgrind, find the base address of your process or library in memory. Do this by examining the `/proc/<PID>/maps` file while your program is running. The line of interest is the `text` segment of your process, which is identifiable by the permissions `r-xp` and the name of your program or library.

Let's say that the base VA is `0x0x4005000`. Then you would find the difference between the valgrind supplied VA and the base VA: `0xbdc`. Then, supply that to add2line:

```
addr2line -e a.out -j .text 0xbdc
```

And see if that gets you your line number.

Comment: wait, what offsets ? Isn't addr2line just takes addresses from symtab (or dyntab) ?

Comment: I got the correct addresses by subtracting the start of the very first range in the map file, which had permissions r--p.  And in my case at least there was an offset even with ALSR off.

Comment: Also worth noting that within the process itself you can use /proc/self/maps

Answer (score 15):

That's exactly how you use it. There is a possibility that the address you have does not correspond to something directly in your source code though.

For example:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -g t.c
$ addr2line -e a.out 0x400534
/tmp/t.c:3
$ addr2line -e a.out 0x400550
??:0
```

`0x400534` is the address of `main` in my case. `0x400408` is also a valid function address in `a.out`, but it's a piece of code generated/imported by GCC, that has no debug info. (In this case, `__libc_csu_init`. You can see the layout of your executable with `readelf -a your_exe`.)

Other times when `addr2line` will fail is if you're including a library that has no debug information.

Comment: In my code I am using pthread and libconfing library. I don't know these libraries has debug info or not.

Answer (score 13):

Try adding the `-f` option to show the function names :

```
addr2line -f -e a.out 0x4005BDC
```