# Debug crash using C Map file in linux?

Tags: c, linux

I have seen a document here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3472/Finding-crash-information-using-the-MAP-file. This example is all about crash seen in Windows file? I am looking for the same mathematics that has been done here for the crash generated on Linux systems. If I get the crash on Linux, then how will I debug the issue in the similar lines like Microsoft document http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3472/Finding-crash-information-using-the-MAP-file. Please help?
Is load address and the code segment address are same in Linux? what is the following in Linux as mentioned in the link "The first part of the binary is the Portable Executable (PE), which is 0x1000 bytes long."?

Comment: Let's say, I have a large software stack. The driver comes from one company, the middleware from other one and the application from another. Now, let's say the application company has stripped the debug information then how will I find a crash in their module. I will get a crash with some address value and symbol ??. This can be solved only if I have a map file. Right?? The question is related to such scenarios keeping in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PE is windows format. Linux uses ELF. Of course you can parse ELF manually, but you shouldn't - gdb could do that for you. Even more, you can use addr2line utility to map address to file/line in source code (of course both of these will require debug build).

Map files are rarely used in linux - it usually just a part of debug executable. It could be dumped from debug build, however, but it don't have too much practical value.

Also, take a look at [How to use addr2line command in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648642/how-to-use-addr2line-command-in-linux)

Comment: Let's say, I have a large software stack. The driver comes from one company, the middleware from one and the application from another. Now, let's say the application company has stripped the debug information then how will I find a crash in their module. I will get a crash with some address value and symbol ??. This can be solved only if I have a map file.

Comment: 'debugging information stripped' means that you don't have a map file, so no symbol for you, only address. Please clarify what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: So,in your opinion, there is no way to find out a crash in a release build variant that has no debug symbols?

Comment: Application developers can - they have debugging symbols, so if you provide crash address to them - they could use addr2line or gdb. If some symbols still remain (e.g. function names) - you could use gdb to find out name of function - but why? What use does it have without source code?

Comment: This is a typical scenario in the integration organisations, where the application is developed by someone, middleware by others and drivers by thirdparty. The crash log is sent to the integrator and he is responsible to fix the issue. No one will take the blame on them, then in such situations how to pin point correctly to the vendors based on the debug logs. I understand if the symbol doesn't belong to your code then it is a third parties. How to boil down to a particular thirdparty, I mean either application or middleware. If I assume that I am a driver guy.

Comment: No one has answered my one more question, Is the load address same as the code segment address by default?

Comment: gdb could tell you if crash address is within elf or shared library. Don't know what you mean by load address tho. Again, if you don't have map - how are you solving this on windows? Strange approach btw, in my view application developers should solve this kind of issues.