# addr2line print "??:0" even i use `gcc -g`

Tags: c, linux

This is my code:

```
/* backtrace_foo1.c */
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BACKTRACE() \
do {\
    void *array[20];\
    size_t size;\
    char **strings;\
    size_t i;\
    size = backtrace(array, 20);\
    strings = backtrace_symbols(array, size);\
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {\
        printf ("%s\n", strings[i]);\
    }\
    free (strings);\
} while(0)

void func1()
{
    BACKTRACE();
}

void func()
{
    func1();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it by `gcc -g -rdynamic` and got

> ./a.out(func1+0x1f) [0x400905]
>
> ./a.out(func+0xe) [0x40097a]
>
> ./a.out(main+0x19) [0x400996]
>
> /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x318ae1ecdd]
>
> ./a.out() [0x4007f9]

Then i use `addr2line -e ./a.out -f 0x4007f9`, i got

> _start
>
> ??:0

This is my platform

> gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)
>
> Linux 3.10.0_1-0-0-8

Comment: For future questions, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And don't forget to actually *ask* one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shouldn't really answer this, since you don't really have a question or a stated problem. But sometimes I'm feeling nice...

While the code you write will start execution with the `main` function, the *actual* starting point is somewhere before that. There is startup code that will initialize the stdio system (`stdin`, `stdout` etc.) and initialize other things. This startup code then calls your `main` function like any other function.

The "problem" is that the startup code is not really part of your code, it's often a precompiled object file that the frontend program links your program with. And that object file probably doesn't have any kind of debug information, so you can't get any location information about it.

Comment: I was ready to hammer this as a dupe to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648642/how-to-use-addr2line-command-in-linux but then it looks to me that your answer differs somehow. Since you have more knowledge on this subject use your judgment for closing it as a dupe or not.

Comment: @bolov The problem in that question is really the same, but the question is different. That question asks about how to use `addr2line` without asking about why information could not be gotten, and the answers follow that line. This question (I assume) is about why `addr2line` provides no information.